# date_default_timezone_set is producing weird results, what gives?

Tags: php, date, timezone

I need to use date_default_timezone_set for my project and it all worked fine until I started using date_diff, as it is producing good and false results depending on the chosen timezone.
An example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$first = date_create("2016-10-01");
$last = date_create("2016-10-31");
$diff = date_diff($first, $last);
echo $diff->d;
```

The result is 30, which is correct.
Now, If I set the timezone to Europe:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

The result is 0.
What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [`var_dump($diff)`](https://eval.in/619016) you will see that the days has reset to zero and month has incremented to 1:

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(1)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(30)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

This is probably due to the fact that [London switches back from DST on the last Sunday in October](https://www.gov.uk/when-do-the-clocks-change). However the date difference is calculated that apparently makes it a "month" as opposed to 30 days.

You can overcome this by using the `days` property [which is will report 30](https://eval.in/619017):

```
$first = date_create("2016-10-01");
$last = date_create("2016-10-31");
$diff = date_diff($first, $last);
echo $diff->days;
```

Comment: Note that the `days` property is 30 when using `America/Los_Angeles` or `Europe/London`. That might be a better option for the OP.

Comment: I'd be glad if you did.